# Capturar meu próprio número de seguidores

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, api, instagram-api

Estou tentando fazer um get do meu número de seguidores via Instagram API.

Já possuo meu *clientId*, meu *userID* e meu *accessToken*. Com o uso do [instafeed.js](http://instafeedjs.com/) já consigo ter acesso ao feed. Porém sempre que eu tento fazer um get a qualquer url:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/?access_token=[MY_ACCESS_TOKEN]
https://www.instagram.com/[MY_PROFILE]/?__a=1
https://www.instagram.com/web/search/topsearch/?query=[MY_QUERY]
```

Caio no problema do Same Origin Policy:

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:5000' is therefore not allowed access.

Já configurei os headers:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', "*");
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods','GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
    next();
})
```

E já tentei usando o `cors`.

Alguém sabe alguma maneira?

Desde já, obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema fazendo a requisição via servidor usando o módulo [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) com o NPM, ao invés de fazer por ajax. Assim não gerou nenhum erro.